# how to manipulate csv from code (cron)? php...? Example: insert+delete column values...

Tags: php, csv, insert

The case is the following:

i have a csv with some columns...

1) i have to automatically insert an empty column between **H** and **I**, so other columns just have to move to the next place I -> J ... J -> K and so on...

2) **O** column values have to become the new **I** column values, and then delete every value contained inside the "old" **O**

3) save the csv

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You have to read the file into memory using [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). Then you can do your magic by manipulating the arrays, using for example [array_splice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php). Finally, you write the "CSV array" back to disk using [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

Answer (score 2):

you can use the Spl library, to see an example:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.setcsvcontrol.php